# Index was not found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am getting error sometimes on CD environment, that The Index "mycustom_web_index" was not found, there is no clear scenario for this, and it is only happens on distributed environment (CM and CD).

I am using solr, and Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

any idea about this error ?

**Updates :**

Note :The main reason that cause this issue because HostingEnvironment environment is shutdown, below is the details

**Detailed explanation of the issue cause from sitecore support:**

1. Sitecore's ShutdownMonitor (object that is managed by the hosting environment) is registered during Sitecore's initialization.
2. A request is started.
3. An application pool and its associated worker processes are being shut down by IIS, for example after a config change. IIS notifies the ASP.NET runtime that the application is shutting down and the worker process for the application pool stops listening for new requests.
4. Hosting environment stops registered objects, including ShutdownMonitor which disposes all search indexes.
5. Request reaches a place in code where search indexes are accessed. As search indexes were already disposed, the request fails to retrieve results from the search index.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Do you have multisites ? and are you using SOLR ?

Comment: Multisites, yes. SOLR, no. We are using SwitchOnRebuild, but for Lucene.

Comment: Actually i am still getting this error sometimes, and i am using SOLR, and it is happens only on production environment, if you have only multisites. i talked to sitecore suppoer team and i sent them my logs files. see their response in the updated section of my question it may help you. and let me know if you find solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

this error is appearing when you try to access an index but it doesn't exist. please check in your index manager if you have the index.
If the index is configured correctly you will see like in the picture.

[image]

If not you need to check index configuration.

Comment: My Index is already there, and this error occurs sometimes not always

Comment: Can you check logs file if you find something related to this problem? if you rebuild your index after this error is thrown is it working fine?

Comment: i am using switchonrebuild for solr, this should don't happen, but on sitecore knolwedge base this was an issue until Sitecore 8.0 update-1, but i am using sitecore 8.1 update 2, see this link : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/398869

Comment: @AymanBarhoum, you need to use the dll and config for other affected Sitecore versions based on the link provided